# removing jPanel from another class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Here's the scenario:
I created a function that can remove or hide the JPanel inside the main panel but if calling it from another class, it won't work.

The function was:

```
public void hideLoginPanel(){
    mainPanel.removeAll();
    mainPanel.repaint();
}
```

I can set anything like setting variable values here but removing the JPanel inside the mainPanel won't work.

Here's the code from another class where I'm calling the function:

```
public class logService{
    private MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
    private static logService dataService;

    public static logService getService() {
        if (dataService == null) {
            dataService = new logService();
        }
        return dataService
    }

    public void removePanel(){
        frame.hideLoginPanel // here's where I called the function
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "won't work"? Are you calling revalidate() after removing the JPanel? Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Are you calling `hideLoginPanel()` from a non-EDT thread? Are you swallowing `Exception`s in your code?

Comment: won't work means no changes at all, i can still click the buttons in the existing panel inside the mainpanel. but if calling the function on the same class, it does the work it removes the panel inside the mainpanel.

sorry if it's kind of confusing.

Comment: @Gábor Bakos im sorry i dont know seriously. but i dont get any printStackTrace errors

Comment: Can you provide more code than this? For example the "other class"?

Comment: @PrincetonMielJurilla You can check with `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread` ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread() ). With multithreading it is not trivial to see `RuntimeException`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code i assume you have created a new object of
MainFrame by using code `private MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();`

Instead you should pass this object to another class from where you are calling mehtod `hideLoginPanel()`. Object can be passed in constructor. Look at these two classes:

```
class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        this.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        LogService logService = new LogService(this); // This object should be used in your control where you want clear panel
        //logService.removePanel(); // Comment and uncomment this line to see the difference. Change in blue color
    }

    public void hideLoginPanel() {
        this.removeAll();
        this.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MainFrame();
    }
}

class LogService {
    private  MainFrame mainFrame;

    public LogService(MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame=mainFrame;
    }

    public void removePanel(){
        mainFrame.hideLoginPanel(); // here's where I called the function
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you give me an example, sorry for being a newbie

Comment: the thing is, from one jpanel class, im calling the logservice class, for the service class to call function from the jframe.

Comment: Since MainFrame is starting point of code. You can always pass its object to other components.

Comment: if it still not work,share the code where logservice object is created

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel nPanel;
    private JLabel label;

    Test() {
        setSize(300,300);
        nPanel = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel("Hello!");
        nPanel.add(label);
        add(nPanel);
    }

    public void clear(JPanel panel) {
        panel.removeAll();
        panel.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setVisible(true);
        t.clear(t.nPanel); //if you comment this line, you will see label said "Hello" to you!
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a way to give your panel to that method,if code's be ok,it should be work,your welcome,give me a minute i will test it for you and edit code's again

Comment: i need to call the function from another class

Comment: it's same,no different!just make your panel and label in another class and create a class with clear method then create object of classes in your Main and use it,good luck:-)